# Edit ASP.NET MVC 3 resx files in deployment server without recompiling

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, deployment, resx, .net

This is my first question here!

I have one ASP.NET MVC 3 Project with a Properties folder, containing some .resx files used to difference content in my views by language (en/es).
I'm working in VS2010 with .Net 4.

When I deploy the application to server, I find that no resx files are published, and instead of it, I have some .dll files.

I have set the build action to `Embedded resource` , `Do not copy` to output directory and `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` as Custom Tool in .resx files properties.

I want to have .resx files on the server and be able to edit them without recompile or redeploy. The views should use those changes.

How can I do that?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I had resx files into Properties folder. Maybe using them from App_GlobalResources folder will let me do that?

Comment: I tried that solution and works!

Comment: PublicResXFileCodeGenerator  seems to be a wrapper for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.tools.stronglytypedresourcebuilder.aspx which converts resx to classes (dlls). Is it necessary for what you're doing?

Comment: Before I found the solution I've tried PublicResXFileCodeGenerator, but it wasn't what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the resx files in your **App_GlobalResources** and change the "Build Action" to **Content** and "Copy To Output Directory" to false.
Make sure the "Custom Tool" is set to **GlobalResourceProxyGenerator**

That should make them changeable even at runtime.

You can simply use xpath to query over them, take the keys, values and comments and edit them as you wish using an XDocument.

You should also know that such a thing won't work with visual studio's publish because App_GlobalResources is not allowed with precompiled website.

Comment: Thanks Adam. When I found that solution I tried and worked fine!

Comment: @Adam Tal, I have follwoed above steps, it is worlking but all sessions are cleared/ app pool is recycled after editing string resource at runtime. How did you maintained that?

Comment: @Pawan - The application pool will recycle once it detects any change in App_GlobalResources - you shouldn't edit the resx a lot! If you have such a need you might consider a database based solution

Comment: @AdamTal, Thanks for suggestion. I have chosen database based solution.  :)